# Why my tag-right in Tkinter is not working?

Tags: python, tkinter, chatbot

I am just learning Tkinter and Python. I am trying to design a chatbot. While designing the chatbot I used tag-right configuration so that, the message shift to right side and response remain in the left side. But the message part is not shifting, now what should i do such that message part shift to right?

Here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEBO0.jpg).

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tkinter.scrolledtext as ScrolledText


def send():
    ChatLog.tag_configure('tag-left', justify='left')
    ChatLog.tag_configure('tag-right', justify='right')
    ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
    frame1 = Frame(ChatLog, bg="#d0ffff")
    Label(
        frame1,
        text="You: Hello",
        font=(
            "Arial",
            11),
        bg="#d0ffff").grid(
            row=0,
            column=0,
            sticky="w",
            padx=5,
        pady=5)
    Label(
        frame1,
        text=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),
        font=(
            "Arial",
            7),
        bg="#d0ffff").grid(
            row=1,
            column=0,
        sticky="w")

    frame2 = Frame(ChatLog, bg="#ffffd0")
    Label(
        frame2,
        text="Bot: Hello",
        font=(
            "Arial",
            11),
        bg="#ffffd0").grid(
            row=0,
            column=0,
            sticky="w",
            padx=5,
        pady=5)
    Label(
        frame2,
        text=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),
        font=(
            "Arial",
            7),
        bg="#ffffd0").grid(
            row=1,
            column=0,
        sticky="w")

    ChatLog.insert('end', '\n', 'tag-right')
    ChatLog.window_create('end', window=frame1)

    ChatLog.insert('end', '\n ')
    ChatLog.window_create('end', window=frame2)
    ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)


base = Tk()
base.title("Chat Bot")
base.geometry("400x500")
base.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
base.configure(bg='white')

ChatLog = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(
    base,
    bd=0,
    bg="white",
    height="8",
    width="50",
    font="Arial")
ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)

SendButton = Button(
    base,
    font=(
        "Verdana",
        12,
        'bold'),
    text="Send",
    width="8",
    height=5,
    bd=0,
    bg="#fd94b4",
    activebackground="#ff467e",
    fg='#ffffff',
    command=send)

EntryBox = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white", width="29", height="5", font="Arial")


ChatLog.place(x=6, y=6, height=386, width=383)
EntryBox.place(x=6, y=401, height=90, width=265)
SendButton.place(x=275, y=401, height=90)

base.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add a space after `\n`: `ChatLog.insert('end', '\n ', 'tag-right')`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the tags. You need to swap the tags.

```
def send():
    ChatLog.tag_configure('tag-left', justify='left')
    ChatLog.tag_configure('tag-right', justify='right')
    ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
    frame1 = Frame(ChatLog, bg="#d0ffff")
    Label(
        frame1,
        text="You: Hello",
        font=(
            "Arial",
            11),
        bg="#d0ffff").grid(
            row=0,
            column=0,
            sticky="w",
            padx=5,
        pady=5)
    Label(
        frame1,
        text=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),
        font=(
            "Arial",
            7),
        bg="#d0ffff").grid(
            row=1,
            column=0,
        sticky="w")

    frame2 = Frame(ChatLog, bg="#ffffd0")
    Label(
        frame2,
        text="Bot: Hello",
        font=(
            "Arial",
            11),
        bg="#ffffd0").grid(
            row=0,
            column=0,
            sticky="e",
            padx=5,
        pady=5)
    Label(
        frame2,
        text=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),
        font=(
            "Arial",
            7),
        bg="#ffffd0").grid(
            row=1,
            column=1,
        sticky="e")

    ChatLog.insert('end', '\n', 'tag-left')
    ChatLog.window_create('end', window=frame1)

    ChatLog.insert('end', '\n ','tag-right')
    ChatLog.window_create('end', window=frame2)
    ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the "tag-right" tab to the line immediately before the line with the label. You need to apply the tag to the line with the window.

Here's one way to do it:

```
ChatLog.window_create('end', window=frame2)
ChatLog.tag_add("tag-right", "end-1c linestart", "end-1c lineend")
```

Since you are using a label to present the actual text, you'll also need to make sure that the text in the label is right-justified, and that the label itself is aligned to the right side of the frame it is in.